# how can i get my local DB data to fill my txt box using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have learned this LINQ code in my School Study guide but they do not show us on text box only show us using properties for data bindings but I need to use LINQ code instead like I have done for the combo box data.

```
public partial class Students : Form
{

    LINQDataClasses1DataContext DB = new LINQDataClasses1DataContext();
    public Students()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Students_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieving data from datbaser using LINQ class convert it to list students ID's
        var StudentIDs = (from c in DB.Students select c).ToList();
        var STudentName = (from c in DB.Students select c).ToString();

        //bind the Student ID combo box to database
        cmbSTID.DataSource = StudentIDs;

        //Databinding setup for the Student ID combo box
        cmbSTID.DisplayMember = "SID";
        cmbSTID.ValueMember = "SID";
        cmbSTID.DataSource = StudentIDs;
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve and what exactly is your question ?

Comment: also, why do you set the dataSource twice?

Comment: sorry I forgot to delete the second datasource.

Comment: pretty sure `var STudentName = (from c in DB.Students select c).ToString();` will either break or else provide nothing useful. i'm also not sure if this code will even compile - where is `cmbSTID` declared?

Comment: I have to use LINQ to fill my text box fields in my forms created to update and edit add or delete teachers in database

Comment: @RonielArmanAcosta exactly which part is giving you difficulty? this isn't a code-writing service...

Comment: that is how I have been taught in my study guides and that current code does fill my combo box with my student ID's

Comment: sorry didn't mean to upset you as i am just seeking help on how to fill a text box with data from a data table in my local DB using LINQ as i know how to do this using databinding in properties setting the databinding text but i am required to do it using LINQ but unsure how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can understand, in your code StudentIDs = StudentName, and it nither a list of students' IDs, nor a list of students' names, but a list of students. Let say you need to show the first student name in a textbox, then try smthing like `textBoxName.Text =  StudentIDs.First().Name`

Comment: this works but what it is, is I have a student from with a student id at the top in a combo box and the rest of the from uses  text boxes like first name last name and address so on and when I use the student id combo box and I choose a students id number it needs to fill my text boxes with the correct data using LINQ

Comment: in combobox.ItemChanged() event, select the student with the selected Id like var student = DB.Students.First(s => s.SID = combobox.Value);then assign to your textboxes values of this student: textBoxFirstName.Text = student.Name; textBoxLastName.Text = student.Surname; and so on

Comment: awesome thanks heaps VDN

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your `Student` class is so I can only guess it looks like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public long SID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Solution is simple:

```
private void Students_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieving data from datbaser using LINQ class convert it to list students ID's
    var studentsList = DB.Students.ToList();

    //Databinding setup for the Student ID combo box
    cmbSTID.DisplayMember = "Name"; //Field name in Student class
    cmbSTID.ValueMember = "SID"; //Field name in Student class
    cmbSTID.DataSource = StudentIDs;
}
```